# How to get the remainder of a big numbers in java

Tags: java

is there any solution to this problem? why it returns 541 instead of 3.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = Math.pow(3, 561);

        // it returns 541 instead of 3
        System.out.println(a % 561);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably a problem with double precision.

Comment: Confirming `471`. This is definately a precision loss problem. Do modular exponentiation if you need accurate results.

Comment: short answer: you don't want to use double to hold a huge integer.

Comment: @Juxhin can you give an example using / ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`double`s don't actually behave as integers. Java's true integer type is `java.math.BigInteger`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger a = new BigInteger("3").pow(561);
    System.out.println(a.mod(new BigInteger("561")));
}
```

Comment: `BigInteger#modPow` is _much_ better because it performs modular exponentiation, wich is much faster for high exponents / bases.

Comment: For large exponents (like `10000000`) this has the disadvantage that a **very** large intermediate result has to be computed. (This is avoided when using `modPow`). However, this it probably not relevant here, so certainly worth a +1... (EDIT: Yeah, AlexR was faster...)

Comment: @AlexR Yes, but I was trying to answer the question as directly as possible.

Answer (score 11):

According to the [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem):

```
Math.pow(a, p) % p == a % p
```

and so:

```
Math.pow(3, 561) % 561 = 3 % 561 = 3
```

Therefore, you don't need to do this heavy calculations. Just maths.

Comment: especially when the heavy calculation exceeds the precision of the data type used.

Comment: My guess is that he's just using this as a test case, because he knows what the modulo is, and wants to know why the calculation is wrong.

Comment: Yes. I didn't see it in the question initially. Anyway, exceeding types is the possible explanation indeed.

Comment: @kocko Fermats theorem states "Fermat's little theorem states that if p is a prime number, then for any integer a, the number a^p − a is an integer multiple of p"

Comment: how does that connects with the above answer you gave

Comment: @Neo That means that a^p mod p = a mod p. He forgot the last mod ;)

Comment: @AlexR yes thats what i was thinking

Comment: I also overlooked this (glad there are many eyes here). So for example, the `Math.pow(3, 560) % 560 = 3` does **not** hold...

Comment: and ... 561 is NOT prime, so Fermat's theorem doesn't apply here.  This answer is entirely incorrect.   (Sorry, Konstantin, I'm not consciously trying to pick on you today - it's just that after I commented on your Mockito answer just now, I had a quick look to see what else you had written, and ended up here).

Answer (score 6):

The `BigInteger` class has a dedicated method for that:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class BigModPow
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BigInteger b = new BigInteger("3");
        BigInteger e = new BigInteger("561");
        BigInteger m = new BigInteger("560");
        BigInteger result = b.modPow(e, m);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

(EDIT: I changed the modulo to be not the same value as the exponent, to show that a non-trivial result is computed - although 561 is not a prime number)

Comment: Nice, but why `m=560`?

Comment: @AlexR: As kocko pointed out: When the exponent is the same as the modulo value, the result is rather boring. I changed this to 560 to show that a non-trivial result is computed.

Comment: Ah okay, so just for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compute something like
`Math.pow(a, b) % m` with *minmal* (not zero) loss of precision, use the modular exponentiation formula:
`Math.pow(a, b) % m = Math.pow(a, b-1) % m * a`
A Java recursive implementation would be:

```
private int modExp(int a, int b, int m) {
    if (b == 0) return 1;
    if (b == 1) return a % m;
    return (a * modExp(a, b-1, m)) % m;
}
```

This is still prone to overflow if `a*(m-1)` is too large for `int`. An alternative is [`BigInteger#modPow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow%28java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger%29) wich uses an equivalent algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Due to problem with double precision you will not get correct result with `double`. Use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

```
 BigDecimal bigDecimal=new BigDecimal("3").pow(561);
 BigDecimal[] bigDecimal1=bigDecimal.divideAndRemainder(new BigDecimal("561"));
 System.out.println(bigDecimal1[1]);
```

[divideAndRemainder()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divideAndRemainder%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) returns a two-element array containing the result of divide To Integral Value followed by the remainder. Remainder is part you are looking for.

Out put:

```
3
```

Comment: +1 as well for the only solution so far that also works for non-integer numbers